# How to analyse efficiency of a simple algorithm in C

Tags: c, performance

Say I am doing a simple task-- a lot.  For this post I will use the example of reducing mod a power of 2-- but this can be any task.

There are many approaches, and it is difficult to determine which one is better.  For example, to reduce a 64-bit unsigned integer `a` modulo `2^b`, we can either do:

- `a - (a >> b << b)`
- `a << (64 - b) >> (64 - b)`
- `a & ((1 << b) - 1)`
- `a % (1 << b)`
- `a & array[b]`, where `array[i]` would contain the value `((1 << i) - 1)` for various `i`'s.  I do not wish to assume that `array[i]` will be in the L1 cache.

Perhaps there are others.  For each of these methods, it is fairly straightforward to determine its cost after looking at the assembly code-- e.g. two shifts and a minus; or two shifts, a single-byte minus, and another minus operation partially optimized away by the compiler.

However, it is difficult to determine, which of these is actually faster on a given architecture.  I have tried the following, but failed:

-- Read documentation on the architecture.  When I can find it, it gives a clear answer as to how many cycles a shift, or an & take-- however, it is still difficult to tell, just how many cycles would a cached minus operation take, or how much of performance drawback I am incurring by pushing useful data out of the cache in order to load the `array[b]` data.

-- Run the same code many million times in a row.  However, this results in the array remaining in the cache, and therefore giving a faster performance.

-- Run the same code many million times, and in between the runs run some code to put / read other data in the cache.  However, there is a lot of variability in the running time, from me putting and accessing data in the cache, and the standard deviation is too big for the results to be reliable.

-- Thanks to a suggestion by @klutt, I pasted these methods into the real code, and the first three methods seem to have equal performance.  What is probably happening is, all three methods can finish executing while the program is waiting for another value to be pulled up from the cache, later on in the program.  However, in case the program changes later (e.g., less cache lookups), then one of these methods might become preferable to the others.

If I do not wish to revisit my reduction mod 2^* code every time the program changes, is there another, better method, to measure which of these is faster?

Comment: If you cannot come up with a method to measure which is fastest, does it really matter?

Comment: For example, this algorithm will be in the frequently-executed section of some performance-oriented program.

Comment: In that case, just try the different methods in the real situation. If you measure a difference, then you know. If you don't it does not matter.

Comment: I do wonder though, what would a "cached minus" be?

Comment: And it also seems to me that if you cannot count on this simple code being in the cache, then it's pointless to optimize it.

Comment: @EOF Thanks, I updated it.

Comment: @klutt So at this point, it does not seem to make a difference (except the last two are definitely slower).  However, the program might change later, and what does not matter now, might matter later.  I'll just revise my post to reflect that.

Comment: And what's true about what's fastest at the moment may also change later on. Would it be hard to change this later?

Comment: As an aside, I think the `google benchmark` framework is worth a look. It does micro-benchmarking quite well. https://github.com/google/benchmark.

Comment: For a power of 2 precalculate a mask such a `0xFFFF` and do a simple `&`. Leave it to the compiler to make more efficient if it can.

Comment: @klutt There might be multiple such sections-- too much to do, visiting them all after every code change.  If you are sure that what's fastest at the moment may also change later on-- then please post this as an answer (with an explanation of how one of the first three computations might be faster than another in one program, and slower in another.)  I thought that a (non-floating point, non-cache, non-IO, etc.) operation would always execute in X CPU cycles on a given CPU, and therefore would either always be faster, or always be slower...

Comment: @WeatherVane If you read my updated post-- this method (#5 in my list) turned out to be slower than the others, if the precalculated values are not staying in the L1 cache.

Comment: I did not notice that `b` might be changing from moment to moment. But if you can't easily determine which is best, does it matter? If it was a serious problem, it would be easy to detect.

Comment: @Alex I definitely don't know what is fastest. In fact, I'm pretty sure it's impossible to determine in advance. Modern cpu:s has a lot of magic in them. What's best on your current cpu might not be on your next. If you're so sure this could be an issue, could you not just do a `#define REDUCE_MOD(a,b) a - (a >> b << b)`?

Comment: @klutt OK, so at this point I feel like I'm repeating my post.  I agree that what's *best* can vary from CPU to CPU.  I stated this as `it is difficult to determine, which of these is actually faster on a given architecture` in my post.  The code you suggested was my first bullet point.  If you are sure that the answer to which of the first three methods is *best* can vary depending on the program, not *just* the CPU, then please post that as an answer, explaining why (or giving an example of how) that can happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I could write something good enough for an answer here. I still don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible. Performance tests always needs to be tested on the whole project. But as a general rule: If the calculations are simple, cache misses are EXTREMELY costly.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these different ways to implement a task (especially if it's a really simple task), will be optimized by the compiler to the exact same machine code instructions. Have you tried exploring http://godbolt.org/ and seeing what machine code instructions each of the different methods compiles to? This might give you a better idea of which ones are better.